# How can I set a default file handle in a perl subroutine signature?

Tags: perl, signature, method-signature

I have a subroutine,

```
use experimental "signatures";

sub foo {
  my $fh = +shift;
  open ($fh, '>', 'default_file') unless defined $fh;
}
```

I would like to port that to subroutine signatures. Is it possible to set $fh to default to a filehandle that points to `default_file`.

Something like this

```
sub foo ($fh=open($fh,">",foo")) {}
```

or even with a `do{}` block,

```
sub foo ($fh=do { open($fh,">",foo"), $fh } ) {}
```

I know I can get this syntax if I use or create a wrapper. But it just seems like there should be a way of some sort to get this done without invoking IO::File and the like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second attempt you showed is almost valid, you just need another variable to stand in since `$fh` doesn't exist yet when assigning the default; and to return it in a separate statement from where it's declared. You could abuse global variables to do this of course but that's ugly and leaky.

```
sub foo ($fh=do { open(my $d,">","foo"); $d } ) {}
```

This of course should have error handling.

```
sub foo ($fh=do { open(my $d,">","foo") or die "Failed to open 'foo': $!"; $d } ) {}
```

A [proposed extension to signatures](https://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl5.porters/2019/11/msg256680.html) could be used to do it slightly differently, but I'm not sure if this is any better:

```
sub foo (?$d, $fh=(open($d,">","foo") || die "Failed to open 'foo': $!", $d) ) {}
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no clean and nice mechanism provided specifically for that.  Given that, I just don't see much value in shoving all that code to open and check a filehandle down the signature itself.

Also, one still needs to check that the passed filehandle is good so there is a need to further process that input.  What puts filehandle management in the body anyway.  So here's a couple of other ways to use signatures for this.

Can have a default that merely indicates that the filehandle has not been passed so that we then open it in the body

```
sub write_to_file ($fname = 'foo.txt', $fh = undef) {
    open $fh, '>', $fname or die $!  if not defined $fh;

    say $fh 64;
}
```

One should really check that input, supposedly a filehandle with a particular mode

```
sub write_to_file ($fname = 'foo.txt', $fh = undef) {
    if (not defined $fh) {
        open $fh, '>', $fname or die $!
    } 
    else {
        # check whether the filehandle's good and its mode
    }

    say $fh 64;
}
```

This looks absolutely natural to me.  We often have to check input anyway.

Or one can cheat, just a little, and use a name-less and value-less [optional argument](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Signatures)

```
use experimental 'signatures';
no warnings 'experimental::args_array_with_signatures';

sub foo ($=) {
    my $fh = shift;
    open $fh, '>', 'foo.txt' or die $!  if not defined $fh;
    say $fh 42;
    return $fh;
}
```

This fakes it in the sense that it uses `@_` to process arguments. However, one of nice things with signatures is that the `@_` is kept pristine and can also be used

> When using a signature, the arguments are still available in the special array variable `@_`, in addition to the lexical variables of the signature.

I don't see a good reason to not use that.<sup>†</sup> Even as it pushes the argument processing back into the sub's body, you still get other benefits of signatures -- and an added measure of flexibility.

---

<sup>†</sup> The stylistic point of handling arguments in the signature, including their defaults, is denied here anyway, merely by how much there is to do for this default.

On the other hand, the ability to use `@_` is still experimental and may change in the future, which is why there is another statement to suppress the warning emitted in newest Perls when `@_` is used.

Comment: This may not work if `@_` is suppressed with signatures enabled in the future.

Comment: @Grinnz Nah, the pristine `@_` is one of the main premises here. (Of course that _anything_ can change in an experimental feature but the availability of `@_` is an important part, since the signature itself isn't meant to deal with all aspects of argument processing.)  Also, the linked page prominently says "_When using a signature, the arguments are still available in the special array variable `@_`..._"

Comment: Currently yes. I am referring to the [proposal to change that](https://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl5.porters/2019/11/msg256681.html) (accompanied by the other proposals, which should serve to deal with all aspects of argument processing).

Comment: @Grinnz Ah well. Thank you for info and the link. I only scanned over (a part of?) the thread but those ideas seem rather complex to me, in particular with implications.  We'll see of course, but for now I feel OK using prominent properties clearly stated in docs. We understand that this _is_ experimental stuff.

Comment: The world has changed and using @_ with signatures is now a warning. It's likely to be an error in the future.

Comment: @briandfoy Yeah, that's why I edited to rearrange and push that down (and to add that warning). Just the other day I ran again into your old article about signatures (in Effective Perler).  The world is changing, yes ... I guess it's good to see that things are moving...?  (One can still use the slurpy last argument to pick up all that's passed in but that's clumsy, and it's copies)

Answer (score 0):

Pending a better answer, I think the only method is to use a wrapper,

```
use IO::File;                                                              
sub foo ( $fh=IO::File->new("default_file", "w") ) {                                
  print $fh 42                                                             
}
```

Comment: [File::Open](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Open) is an even better wrapper for this case, since it includes error handling.